# SQL Query issue with joining data don't exist in table

Tags: mysql, sql, join

[image]

I have two tables as seen above.
Lets call it Table1 and Table2

and we get result table. which give accumulated result.

```
SELECT T1.c_id,T1.p_name, T2.Date, IF(T2.Date IS NULL,0,COUNT(COALESCE(T2.count_p_id, 0))) AS count_p_id
FROM (
SELECT a.company_id, b.id, a.p_id, b.name 
        FROM table1 a, product_info_table b 
        WHERE a.p_id = b.p_id
            AND a.c_id = 15
) AS T1 
LEFT JOIN (
SELECT c_id,p_id, Date, COUNT(p_id) AS count_p_id
    FROM table2
    WHERE Date BETWEEN '2016-01-01' AND '2016-01-31' 
    GROUP BY DATE(Date)
) AS T2 ON T2.p_id = T1.p_id 
GROUP BY DATE(T2.Date)
```

problem is all date is not showing, only the date that exist in table2 shows. I need to show all date within the date range and show them as '0'

This is not giving the correct result. what am I doing wrong? any help would be good?

I am using mySQL.

Comment: The general GROUP BY rule says: If a GROUP BY clause is specified, each column reference in the SELECT list must either identify a grouping column or be the argument of a set function!

Comment: @jarlh: This general rule is not applicable in mysql case.

Comment: @haytem, I know MySQL is "flexible" when it comes to group by, but if you follow this rule you'll never go wrong!

Comment: so what am i doing wrong? please help

Comment: You don't have the field date from table1 in your select. Why do you expect it to be selected then?

Comment: You should find a solution at the "duplicate question" link.

Comment: @haytem I have date in SELECT

Comment: @Tom I did look at it, but its different, its asking me to create calendar table

I have a date range, 1 to 10 and it only show date that exist in table. I need all date within date range and show them 0 if not exist